# Getting error while clicking on the button on which I am calling Async task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is my code in which on clicking I am calling AttemptLogin method.

```
class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


EditText editEmail, editPassword, editName;
Button btnSignIn, btnRegister;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

String URL= "https://xyz/restapi/registration";

JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();

int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    btnRegister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    /*btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AttemptLogin attemptLogin= new AttemptLogin();
            attemptLogin.execute(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText().toString(),"");
        }
    });*/

    /*btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            }


    });*/
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new AttemptLogin().execute();
}

private class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for registering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {





        ArrayList params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cust_firstname", "Sai"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cust_lastname", "Kumar"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cust_phoneno", "9989219692"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cust_confirmpass", "Sai@123"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cust_pass", "Sai@123"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cust_username", "sai@gmail.com"));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);


        return json;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

}

on button click i want to post data directly but getting error as

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

If there are any nice tutorials for registering details for Async task means please let me know.

Comment: On which button you are clicking.

Comment: Your button is working fine check button id in your xml.

Comment: Have you initialized your buttons properly? You are getting NPE, since you haven't casted  `btnSignIn` which might be in your XML resource.

Comment: Thanks guys i had kept wrong xml file in my code thats why got error sorry for troubling.  can you please help me out in posting the details. I am getting error as Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!doctype of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId){
    case R.id.button:
   new AttemptLogin().execute();
 }
}
```

try this one

Comment: getting same error even after using switch case that you given

Comment: is your api perfectly working in postman? did u check that?

Comment: Api is working fine i had kept other xml file in the code so thats the error sorry for the trouble. can you please help me out in posting the details. I am getting error as Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!doctype of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

The ***id*** of the button is correct? It corresponds with the ***id in XML layout***?

Use in onCreate:

```
 btnRegister.setOnClickListener(btnLoginClick);
```

Then, out of the onCreate declare method:

```
private View.OnClickListener btnLoginClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          ...
          //write your code
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnRegister: 
              new AttemptLogin().execute();
              break;
            default:
              break;
    }
 }
```

The official Android Developer site should be your closed friend. Make sure you read this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask